# Correct "select all" checkbox with jQuery

Tags: jquery

http://briancray.com/tests/checkboxes/index.html

The ways to implement select all is simple, but not perfect. The select all and unselect all works fine, but when under select all state, if you uncheck one the select all is also checked. How can this be corrected?

[image]

then

[image]

"Check all" is still checked. How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>Warning, shameless self-promotion ahead.</sub>

I've written a plugin for jQuery that does exactly this sort of thing. Have a look: http://mjball.github.com/jQuery-CheckAll

To use it with the markup on the page you linked:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="myform"> 

<fieldset> 
    <div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkall" id="checkall"> <label for="checkall">Check all</label></div> 
    <div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1"> <label for="checkbox1">Checkbox</label></div> 
    <div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2"> <label for="checkbox2">Checkbox</label></div> 
    <div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3"> <label for="checkbox3">Checkbox</label></div> 
    <div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4"> <label for="checkbox4">Checkbox</label></div> 
    <div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" id="checkbox5"> <label for="checkbox5">Checkbox</label></div> 
    <div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6" id="checkbox6"> <label for="checkbox6">Checkbox</label></div> 
    <div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox7" id="checkbox7"> <label for="checkbox7">Checkbox</label></div> 
    <div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox8" id="checkbox8"> <label for="checkbox8">Checkbox</label></div> 
    <div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox9" id="checkbox9"> <label for="checkbox9">Checkbox</label></div> 
    <div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox10" id="checkbox10"> <label for="checkbox10">Checkbox</label></div> 
</fieldset> 

</form>
```

This will suffice:

```
$('#checkall').checkAll('#myform input:checkbox:not(#checkall)');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/npeTz/

<s>CheckAll works correctly with jQuery 1.4.4 and 1.5.2. I have not had time to update it for jQuery 1.6. <sub>sorry.</sub></s>

---

Updated for jQuery 1.6 compatibility: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/CVQsp/

---

It still works even if you accidentally select the master along with the slaves: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/BwFvc/

Comment: Even tho it's shameless self promotion, I would always recommend using a plugin if you can't write the code yourself in 20 minutes or so....

Comment: @zhuanzhou can you update to at least 1.4.2? [jQuery 1.2.6](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.6.js) is **really** old (it was released 2008-05-24 - over 3 years ago).

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take on it.

```
var checkall = $('#checkall');
var boxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(checkall);

checkall.click(function () {
    boxes.attr('checked', this.checked);
});
boxes.change(function() {
    checkall[0].checked = this.checked && boxes.filter(':checked').length === boxes.length;
});
```

This way the `checkall` gets checked even if you manually check all the sub boxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/T4EK2/

Comment: Howdy @Matt Ball. How could I stay away? Gotta feed the addiction. ;o)

Comment: what's these lines meaning?    checkall[0].checked = this.checked && boxes.filter(':checked').length === boxes.length;  and could i change this boxes.attr('checked', this.checked); to boxes.attr('checked', checked); thank you.

Comment: @zhuanzhou: `checkall[0]` grabs the DOM element out of the jQuery object and sets its `.checked` property. It is set to `true` if `this.checked` is `true (`this` being the element that received the event) *and* if the number of checked boxes is equal to the total number of boxes. And no, you'd need `boxes.attr('checked', this.checked);`. When the `checkall` element is clicked, if its `.checked` property is `true`, then the `checked` property of all the `boxes` will be set to `true`, likewise if `false`.

Comment: +1 This is perfect. Short, sweet, ***no plugins necessary***. Very elegant, user113716! *Almost* tempted to register more SE accounts just to upvote more. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the state change of the child checkboxes too.
Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () {
    $('#checkall').click(function () {
        $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
       //THIS IS NEW ADDITION TO YOUR CODE
    $('input[id^="checkbox"]').click(function(){
     if(!this.checked){
        $('#checkall').attr("checked", false)
     }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are similar answers already. I'm gonna post this anyway since I spent some time making it work and learning something new. <strike>**Doesn't work with v1.6**</strike>

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/gsndd/</strike>

http://jsfiddle.net/gsndd/2/

```
$(function() {
    // Ripped from https://github.com/mjball/jQuery-CheckAll @Matt Ball 
    var propFn = typeof $.fn.prop === 'function' ? 'prop' : 'attr';

    $('#checkall').click(function() {
        $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find(':checkbox')[propFn]('checked', this.checked);
    });
    $("input[type=checkbox]:not(#checkall)").click(function() {
        if (!this.checked) {
            $("#checkall")[propFn]('checked', this.checked);
        } else {
            $("#checkall")[propFn]('checked', !$("input[type=checkbox]:not(#checkall)").filter(':not(:checked)').length);
        }

    });
});
```

<strike>**EDIT:** To make the same work with v1.6+, just change the `attr` to `prop`. Ultimately, you are better off using something that works with both.</strike>

**Edit** - Fixed the code to work on any version(assuming John won't come up with v1.7 and say, 'surprise').
Thanks to @Matt Ball

Comment: It's easy to make it work with both - have a look at my plugin's source.

Comment: @Matt Ball - thanks sir, I fixed it. Its been like 10 days since I'm learning jQuery by answering questions on SO and tips like these are just awesome.

Comment: what's this line meaning? var propFn = typeof $.fn.prop === 'function' ? 'prop' : 'attr'; thank you

Comment: It just checks if `prop` is a function and if it is then it stores prop in the variable propFn. It stores attr otherwise. Since prop is available starting v1.6 only, this will pick up the correct method depending on what is available in the jQuery library. @Matt Ball can correct me if I'm wrong.