# some code i don't understand well in jquery

Tags: jquery

1,`$('input[id^="checkbox"]').click(function()`

what's the `id^="checkbox"` meaning?

2,

```
var checkall = $('#checkall');
var boxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(checkall);

checkall.click(function () {
    boxes.attr('checked', this.checked);
});
boxes.change(function() {
    checkall[0].checked = this.checked && boxes.filter(':checked').length === boxes.length;
});
```

a, `var boxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(checkall);`

does this line mean "give all `type=checkbox` input to boxes expect the `id=checkall"`

what's these lines meaning? `checkall[0].checked = this.checked && boxes.filter(':checked').length === boxes.length`; and could i change this `boxes.attr('checked', this.checked)`; to `boxes.attr('checked', checked);` thank you

Comment: id^="checkbox" -> all the input that the id start with checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. all `input` elements that have id starting with letters "checkbox" like id=checkbox, id=checkbox1, id=checkboxABC etc
2. `var boxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(checkall);`
   means get all input elements of type checkbox except the one with id=checkall
3. `checkall[0].checked = this.checked && boxes.filter(':checked').length === boxes.length;`
   set $('#checkall')'s checked property to  true if all checkboxes in the `boxes` is checked. This is done by checking if the total number of checked checkboxes is equal to total number of checkboxes. The first part `this.checked` is not required but it doesn't hurt. If current element if unchecked this first part will prevent the second part from executing and will set the status to false which is what you want.
4. No, you can't change `boxes.attr('checked', this.checked)` to `boxes.attr('checked', checked)`. You could've tried that yourself.

if anyone is wondering how I answered these, I was helping OP solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338987/correct-select-all-checkbox-with-jquery) question yesterday and I know what OP was asking.